# Continuous Mapping on Topological Spaces

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Question:

Let X be [0, 1] ∪ [2, 4]. 
Define f : X → R by f(x) = 1 when x ∈ [0, 1] and
f(x) = 2 when x ∈ [2, 4]. Prove that f is continuous.

Solution:

The restriction of f to [0, 1] is continuous (it is constant), so is the restriction
of f to [2, 4] (it is also constant). RTP $$ f^{-1}(A)$$ is open if A is open. But A is the
union of its intersections with the two clopen subsets [0, 1] and [2, 4]. Suppose A is
open. $$ f^{−1}(A) = f^{−1}(A ∩ [0, 1]) ∪ f^{−1}(A ∩ [2, 4]) $$. We have already shown these subsets are open.

Can someone explain the solution to me?
What I mainly don't understand is: 
1) According to Munkres Topology without Tears Chapter 5, the restriction of a continuous function is continuous. And in here without showing that f is continuous, they are already saying that f to the respective intervals are continuous??

2) How did they define A? The last line of proof makes no sense to me.

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: The function is locally constant, hence locally continuous. Do you know that locally continuous is equivalent to continuous?

Comment: The solution seems overly complicated. For any subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$, the preimage $f^{-1}(A)$ can only be one of four things: $\emptyset$ if neither $1$ nor $2$ belongs to $A$; $[0,1]$ if $1 \in A$ and $2 \not\in A$; $[2,4]$ if $2 \in A$ and $1 \not\in A$; or $[0,1] \cup [2,4]$ if $\{1,2\} \subseteq A$. All of these four possible preimages are open in the relative topology on $[0,1] \cup [1,2]$. So the pre-image of *every* set---hence certainly every open set---is open.